# svchost.exe suspended returns null when trying to 'end task'

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, svchost

I started getting this weird issue where `windows explorer` crashes (could be a side effect) and then when trying to restart `windows explorer` process it shuts down but does not start up again, running it manually from `task manager` does not work either...

So far I have found that at the process list there is a process that is in a `suspended` state, and when I went to file location it was windows `svchost.exe`

I could not debug it any further since no new programs could be run, I couldn't make a screenshot so made a photo...

[image]

Update: in Event Viewer found this

> The program svchost.exe version 10.0.17134.1 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and Maintenance control panel.
>   Process ID: c50
>    Start Time: 01d45987ade68050
>    Termination Time: 60000
>    Application Path: C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
>    Report Id: 8c9698ef-455b-44d2-bc3e-4e7f7c973d08
>    Faulting package full name:
>    Faulting package-relative application ID:

I also tried to do memory dump but `C:\Windows\LiveKernelReports` is empty so I guess that bit failed too...

Here's [svchost.exe in question](https://files.fm/u/fvejk46m)

**What is happening? How do I fix this or debug further?**

Comment: It's actually called File Explorer since you are running Windows 10.  File Explorer isn't required to run an application like Paint.  You will have to narrow down the cause of the behavior by running in a minimum configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound Hi, It happened second time now, in like ~2 weeks, I am unable to reproduce issue after restarting laptop until it happens spontaneously again... I tried navigating to paint.net via `open file location` in task manager, but when I launched it didn't go...

Comment: `svchost.exe` is required, your first revision, didn't include a screenshot.